# Is there a way to write application logs like Tomcat and PostgreSQL to Tenable Log Correlation Engine?

Tags: logging, tomcat, postgresql, syslog

My IT group uses Tenable's Log Correlation Engine and we have our Linux servers writing syslog to LCE. Is there a way to write our Tomcat and PostgreSQL application logs to LCE?

Comment: pg and tomcat can both write their logs to syslog. can you not use that?

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan, after further research, it looks like we're going to have to enable that. Please answer the question so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL and Tomcat can write their logs to syslog.

For PG, see the docs here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html

For Tomcat, you can configure it to use Log4j and Log4j supports syslog:

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html#Using_Log4j